# Adding additional attributes to an Enum object

Tags: php, enum

I have used Enum objects before in PHP as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enums).

However, I often find it's a requirement to have further attributes or metadata available on the instances.

I came up with the example solution below:

```
<?php

class Month {
    const January = 1;
    const February = 2;
    const March = 3;
    const April = 4;
    const May = 5;
    const June = 6;
    const July = 7;
    const August = 8;
    const September = 9;
    const October = 10;
    const November = 11;
    const December = 12;

    protected $value;

    protected static $metadata = [
        1 => ['days_in_month' => 31],
        2 => ['days_in_month' => 28],
        3 => ['days_in_month' => 31], 
        4 => ['days_in_month' => 30], 
        5 => ['days_in_month' => 31], 
        6 => ['days_in_month' => 30], 
        7 => ['days_in_month' => 31], 
        8 => ['days_in_month' => 31], 
        9 => ['days_in_month' => 30], 
        10 => ['days_in_month' => 31], 
        11 => ['days_in_month' => 30], 
        12 => ['days_in_month' => 31]
    ];

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, static::$metadata[$this->value])) {
            return static::$metadata[$this->value][$name];
        }
    }
}

$month = new Month(Month::February); // Returns Month instance
$month->days_in_month; // Returns 28 (for February)
```

Obviously the metadata array can be expanded to include further attributes that should be available for each enumerable option. And of course this need to throw exceptions / handle problems.

Feedback appreciated. Is there a better way to have an Enumerable-type approach which can include additional attributes?

Comment: What are you using this for, where April to December aren't needed?

Comment: I used three months to keep the script short and easy to read - it's an example, you can use imagination to fill out the rest ;)

Comment: There *is* a serious point hidden in my tongue-in-cheek remark - here on Code Review, we prefer *complete* code where we don't have to imagine what you wrote.  (That said, it's good that you include February, which doesn't always have 28 days).

Comment: As you seem to be a [so] user, it's worth reading [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778).  It will tell you what's expected here that's different to what you're used to.

Comment: Thanks for the intro. I have completed the code. Some constructive feedback around the problem I'm trying to solve would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

February doesn't necessarily have 28 days.  In some years, it has 29 days.  This code produces the wrong answer for around ¼ of Februaries.